# MySQL How to calculate how many times a whole number fits in another number and what's left from it

Tags: mysql, sql

For school I need to make an assigment where I need to make an overview if a vehicle needs to go for maintenance soon. I have data of vehicles with their mileages. In this case every vehicle needs to go for maintenance after every 20000 KM/12000 Miles.

So example vehicle A has a total of 198255 KM/123189.9 Miles.

How do I calculate this?

I know 20000 KM/12000 Miles fits 9.91 times in 198255.

The WHOLE number 20000 fits 9 times in 198255 and what's left is 182555.

This is the result that I need to get for every vehicle.

Can someone please explain how I can calculate this and get the wanted result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really want to calculate this based on the *last* time the vehicle went in for maintenance.  You don't want to do it since the beginning of time, because you don't know if a vehicle has followed the rules.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your fast response! I should have mentioned that there is no info when they went last time for maintenance.

Comment: So this is a question about basic arithmetic?

Comment: With MySQL use `MOD()`.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical concept you're looking for is called "modulo". In computer science, it is often called "integer division".